# huge files size when browserifying angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, browserify

I am just trying gulp + angular + browserify app and got a huge browserified file, about 2M. While all it does just require angular and a sample controller.

```
// setup gulp task
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
  gulp.src([util.format('%s/app/main.js', JS_BASE_DIR)])
  .pipe(browserify({
    insertGlobals: true,
    debug: true
  }))
  // Bundle to a single file
  .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
  // Output it to our dist folder
  .pipe(gulp.dest(util.format('%s/js/', BUILD_BASE_DIR)));
}); 


//in the main.js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var angular = require('angular');

  var indexCtrl = require('./controllers/indexCtrl');

  var app = angular.module('wohu.app', []);

  app.controller('ctrl', indexCtrl);
})();
```

angular is installed via

```
npm install angular
```

The bundle.js is not minified but it shouldn't be that huge. Wonder what the problem is.

Comment: I'm not familiar w/browserify, but I went and read the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/browserify/info) for the browserify tag here on stack overflow. It seems some bloat is expected based on what it is doing ... it's adding more than just angular and your sample controller to the file. The bloat is even listed as one of the cons to using browserify.

Comment: Seems browserify generates a huge source map like "//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbIi9Vc2Vycy95dWp1bi9kZXZlbG9wZXIvd29vaHUvbm9kZV..." which doubles the file size

Comment: It might be a bit late for the answer but can come useful to others. While testing my application in Firefox I discovered it doesn't cache files by default like Chrome does. I looked into Network tab and was unpleasantly surprised by the size of my browserify bundle produced, which was 6mb.

I started extracting other modules that I required inside the bundle but wouldn't make much of a difference. In the end after some juggling I discovered it was 'debug: true' property, which produced source maps. Remove it from a production release and you'll be fine. Thanks, Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Browserify will include a source map in the bottom of the file which can make it seem HUGE. You can strip this out (and you should) for production. You can use exorcist for this (https://www.npmjs.com/package/exorcist) which pulls the source map into an external file for you and can be hooked up to your build process (I use Grunt but will work for Gulp too).